# How to know a file cannot be downloaded from its url without authorization in java/android?

Tags: java, android, urlconnection

My android application can download files from urls with a particular file pattern (say *.pdf).

But some url's which require user's authorization before a file can be downloaded. I dont want to show the authorization screen for such url's. I just want to convey to the user that this file cannot be downloaded by this application.

how do i do this in java/android?

```
void download(String url)
{
    URL url = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    //TODO : stop download if detected that this url requires authorization/authentication.

    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: check the [http status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) you get when you try to download it?

Comment: Get the http response code for that url, if it is 401 then show  login page.

Comment: m getting the response code as -1 and not 401. :(

Comment: Maybe show some code?

Answer (score 0):

Please get the HTTP status from the response as below.

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");//Or POST, depending on your service
connection.connect();

int code = connection.getResponseCode();
```

This should return a 401 if your web service is a Restful service.